# How to redirect from specific subdirectory to a subdomain via .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to redirect this URL (and all its substructures):

```
http://example.com/archive/
```

to (and its corresponding substructures):

```
http://archive.example.com/
```

**For example**: `http://example.com/archive/signature/logo.png ==> http://archive.example.com/signature/logo.png`

I tried to generate an .htaccess rule using a generator and evaluating it by looking at the regex, which I can understand (I think).

The result was the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://example.com/archive/(.*) http://archive.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The way I see it, the server will proccess any URL that starts with `http://example.com/archive/` , will capture the string that comes next and will change the whole initial portion with the subdomain structure and append the captured string.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work neither on my server, nor on online testing tools such as: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Is there anything I'm missing there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to try it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archive/(.*)$ http://archive.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that I did not make it dynamic as you didn't specific if you will have more URL's that need to work this way as well or not.

Comment: This one worked like a charm! Thank you :)
I just wonder what is wrong with the rule I created... Would you point it out to me?

Comment: Oh, and it's OK not to be dinamic, since I only need this specific case

Comment: That generator is useless. The pattern in a rewriterule can't be the full URL. It is only the `URI` that is matched, the part after the hostname. So it never matched because you had `http://example.com/` included in the pattern. Have a look here [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and Read the section **What is Matched?**

Comment: It seems the generator is only for people who actually understand .htaccess :P

Comment: Yeah just read over the documentation on Mod_rewrite, it can take a bit to understand but the info is there. Also look over other examples, those are really helpful as well.